# How to hash password element of array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have class `UserService` which has 2 functions. `CreateUser()` add user to database and `hashPassword()` hash password. But now I have a problem with hash password. Show me error `password_hash(): Argument #1 ($password) must be of type string, array given`. So what could I resolve this problem ?

```
class UserService
{
    public function createUser(RegistrationRequest $request): void
    {
        $this->hashPassword($request->correctValidate());
        User::create($request);
    }

    private function hashPassword($request)
    {
        $password = $request['password'] = Hash::make($request);
      return $password;

    }

}
```

```
public function correctValidate()
{
    return $this->validated();
}
```

Comment: Can you also post here your `correctvalidate()` function? Make sure your `correctvalidate()` function returns a string.

Comment: @aceraven777 I post `correctValidate()`

Comment: Better place for password hashing would be in `creating` event of observer related to User model. That's the action tightly related to User model, not to some service nor request object.

Answer (score 1):

If you add something like this to the user model, it will do it automatically.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Hash::make` function is requiring you to pass string, hence `$request` in `hashPassword` should be string also.

There's many ways for you to solve this. As long as you pass string to the `Hash::make` function you should be golden.

You should learn how to be able to pass data properly. Its pretty much straightforward, if you pass string to a function that function will receive a string.

To answer your problem, this is one solution:

```
public function createUser(RegistrationRequest $request): void
{
    $validated = $request->correctValidate();
    $this->hashPassword($validated['password']);
    User::create($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?
....

```
private function hashPassword($request)
{
    
  return Hash::make($request->input('password'));

}
```

....

Comment: No that's not work, show error `Call to a member function input() on array`

Comment: If you have converted request data into an array you must pass the correct value to the Hash::make function return `Hash::make($request['password']); `Because in your original code you are passing all the request which is an array.